# Derive the distribution of the range of a sample of size 2 from a distribution having density function $f(x) = 2x, 0 <x < 1.$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Derive the distribution of the range of a sample of size 2 from a distribution having density function  $f(x) = 2x, 0 <x < 1.$ Can someone explain to me what the question is asking? I don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the two random variables be $X_1$ and $X_2$. The question is asking for the distribution of the random variable $W$, where $W=\max(X_1,X_2)-\min(X_1,X_2)$, or equivalently for the distribution of $W=|X_1-X_2|$.